# How to create endless session for mobile app

Tags: spring-boot, security, oauth-2.0, architecture

**Current situation**

We have a very common system architecture with Spring Boot back-end and Angular front-end. For the mobile app we use Ionic, which basically uses same codebase as the front-end but adds additional features like biometrics etc.

User login is based on OAuth and access and refresh tokens are created once the user initiates the session. The access token has a short life span, where the refresh token is valid for a couple of days. As I said - very common auth flow.

**What we want to achieve**

- Mobile app users should be able to login only once and then use the
  app without the need to re-login every time the refresh token
  expires.
- For the "normal" front-end app refresh token expiration
  policy should stay unchanged, meaning the user is forced to log in
  again once the refresh token expires.

**Possible solutions (from my perspective)**

- we pass an additional param to the login request specifying the client: web | mobile. If client is mobile refresh token validity is extended to expire in 1-2 years. Downside: this will break the whole idea of having tokens, that expire. I personally see this as a security issue.
- we store credentials on mobile app local storage. Once we have session expiration, the app uses the credentials to re-authenticate. Downside: again I don't think this is a good idea having credentials stored on any device makes the flow vulnerable.

What I am looking for is kind of a best practice to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, It's a security risk to have tokens that never expire or expire in a few years but they are used. Anyway, one thing you could do is to add a field in the refresh token endpoint that when you set it to true (defaults to false) it would also extend the lifespan of the refresh token. And you could periodically call that endpoint from your app. It should work even when It's in the background.

Or

If you wanna store the credentials in the local storage at least store them encrypted. You might need to create an endpoint that encrypts them because you should not have the private key in the mobile app. Then you'll probably need to create a custom authentication method that takes the encrypted credentials and compares them with the ones in the database.

Comment: I'll try to provide some code snippets later tonight.